# Searching and filtering through list elements JS

Tags: javascript, search

In todolist i try to search my values so that i use indexOf!=-1 property ,when i console log everything works but i dont see that on screen strangely, i want to see only what i search.

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 mx-auto mt-5">
        <div class="card p-4">
             <h3 class="result-title">My Program</h3>
             <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search"/>
          <div class="card-body ">
             <ul class="result-list">
                <li class="result-item">Go to the Shop</li>
             </ul>
          </div>
        </div>      
         <div class="card mt-5 p-5">
          <h3> Add Here </h3> 
             <form>  
              <input type="text" class="addtext"  placeholder="SOME "/>
              <button class="addbutton">Add </button>
             </form>
          </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS file

```
// ADDING ITEM //
document.querySelector(".addbutton").addEventListener("click",(event)=>{ event.preventDefault()
const text=document.querySelector(".addtext").value
const asd=document.createElement("li") 
asd.classList.add("result-item") ;
asd.innerHTML=text
document.querySelector(".result-list").appendChild(asd)
document.querySelector(".addtext").value=""
     } )

     //SEARCH ITEM//
 const search=document.querySelector(".search")
    search.addEventListener("change",()=>{
 const list=document.querySelectorAll(".result-item")
        search.value.toLowerCase()
       list.forEach(item=>{ 
if(item.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.value)!=-1) {item.style.display==="block"}else{;item.style.display==="none"}})                    })
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by, *when i console log everything works*. What did you log and why does it mean it works? Also, please fix your code indentation. It will make it much more readable.

Comment: ````if(item.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.value)!=-1) {item.style.display==="block"}else{;item.style.display==="none"}})````
here, i did put some console.log("text") for if statement to see if its working and it works but doesnt filter my items below.

Comment: `===` is doing a comparison, which in that context does nothing (you aren't using the result of the compare).

Comment: Thanks now it works , one more thing ;when i search i see results but list style type turns into none,i mean its not showing up like list item,  is it because display:block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use `=`, not `===`.

```
item.style.display="block"}else{;item.style.display="none"}
```

One equal sign changes the value, while two or three compare the value.